# Multiple Proxy/ReverseProxy on Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I have a service on port 3000 with Proxy/ReverseProxy on Apache at Port 80 on `http://myserver/foo`.

I want to put another server on port 3456 and Proxy/ReverseProxy it from `http://myserver/bar` on Apache as well.

What would be the best strategy?

My `foo.conf` on `httpd/conf.d`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?$ /foo/ [R=permanent,L]
  <Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
  </Location>
  ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:3000 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically just repeat what you already have for the `/bar` URL-path as well. Except you'll need to move the existing `ProxyPassReverse` directive inside the `<Location>` section. (In your current config, you don't strictly *need* the `<Location>` section.)

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?$ /foo/ [R=permanent,L]

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000 
  </Location>
  <Location "/bar">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3456
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3456
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Although this `<VirtualHost>` container would seem incomplete since you have no `ServerName` (`ServerAlias`, `ErrorLog`, etc.) directive(s). So I assume these are already defined in the main server config?

Comment: Got an error message `ProxyPassReverse can not have a path when defined in a location`

Comment: @HufflepuffBR There is no "path" argument in what I have posted above. (?) Note that when the `ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:3000` directive is moved inside the `<Location>` section, the `/foo` path argument is removed. Do you have any other directives? Do you have a corresponding `<VirtualHost *:443>` container?